# Can't run npm after installing

Tags: npm, npm-install

I've seen many similar posts on this here on SO but for some reason those solutions don't seem to work for me. Clearly I'm missing something.

I installed `depcheck` package globally by running `npm install -g depcheck` which ran fine without any errors.

If I go into the global directory for `npm packages` which is:
`c:\Users\<Username>\AppData\Roaming\npm` on my Windows 10 machine, I do see the `depcheck.cmd` file.

I also see the `depcheck` folder within `c:\Users\<Username>\AppData\Roaming\npm\npm_modules` folder.

I think this means I was able to install the `depcheck` package globally.

When I run `npm config get prefix`, I get `c:\Users\<Username>\AppData\Roaming\npm` which seems to be the correct path.

Why is it that when I run `depcheck` inside my project's root folder where the `package.json` is located, I get:

> 'depcheck' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file

If I try another standard `npm command` inside my project's root folder, it works fine. For example, I ran `npm -v` and got the version number.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also had this problem before. After searching on the web I found that reinstalling NPM with Administrator permissions worked for me, as the installer without Administrator permissions doesn't create/write to some specific  files. I hope this will help for you.

Pascal.

Comment: Are you on a Windows machine? My research is telling me that reinstalling `npm` on Windows is best done by reinstalling `node.js`. Is that what you did?

Comment: Reinstalling `node.js` did the trick. Ultimately, I think you were right that reinstalling `npm` is the solution. Because I'm on a Windows machine, I had to reinstall `node.js` which automatically reinstalled `npm`. Thank you for your help.